# Microsoft To-Do is Stuck Exporting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, to-do

Not sure if this is a known problem but I tried to export my Microsoft To-Do list from my Outlook account and even though it says it will take up to 4 days, it's been over a month and it still says export in progress.

I can't find a way to stop or reset it so is there a workaround to export this list?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: In Outlook: File > Open & Export > Import/Export > Export to a file > Comma Separated Values > Select your Tasks...
Now you can remove your account from Outlook client and re-configure it or you can create and use a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile to stop the progress.

Comment: You're talking about https://outlook.live.com/mail/options/general/export , right? It's been stuck for weeks for my account too. We're not alone, apparently : https://todo.uservoice.com/forums/597175-feature-suggestions/suggestions/34855522-ability-to-backup-export-all-lists Sigh... It's been really easy to import from Wunderlist, but Microsoft ToDo seems to be a dead-end, with no available export.

Comment: UserVoice for ToDo is now 404. Well, I guess that's one way to h̶i̶d̶e̶ solve the problem.

Comment: Did any of you manage to export your data? Or is it still stuck after all those years? @EricDuminil

Comment: @Yarin: I don't remember exactly. I think that after a loooong time, I received a kinda useless json, with many missing information.